# How can I install a specific(old) version of Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I would like to test if something works with a previous version of Anaconda. Is there a way for me to install a specific version?

Comment: What specifically you want to test? Don't you have a CI environment or a minimum version target?

Comment: This question is about the version of Anaconda, not the version of Python in a conda environment. I don't think the move to make it already answered by another post is correct, because that question is about the Python version. I also want to know how to get an older version of conda/miniconda.

Answer (score 8):

There's no need to download an old version of Anaconda installation package. Just create an environment and install an old version of Python.

```sh
# create an environment with old version Python, conda
conda create -n venv-name python=3.6 conda=4.6
conda activate venv-name
conda deactivate venv-name
```

`conda` is both a powerful package manager and environment manager. Creating different environments with different versions of Python installed within is a very basic function of `conda`.

- base environment = Python + `conda` package
- Anaconda = base env + meta package `anaconda`.
- meta package `anaconda` = 260+ other packages

`anaconda` is a **meta package**, which **does not contain actual software** and simply depends on other packages to be installed.

#### Extended Reading

- [meta package `anaconda`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57985481/5101148)
- [get started with `conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 6):

I found an archive of old Anaconda packages:

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded one for my old Windows 7 laptop from here:

https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/